# Convert Json String to a Datatable with headers

Tags: jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I have a Json string and i need to create a Datatable with headers from that json string.( and also need to remove the escape characters )

### Json String

```
[\r\n  {\r\n    \"NewsDate\": \"2018-05-05T06:00:00\",\r\n    \"GeoDate\": \"2018-05-02T00:00:00\",\r\n  },
{\r\n    \"NewsDate\": \"2018-06-05T06:00:00\",\r\n    \"GeoDate\": \"2018-06-02T00:00:00\",\r\n  }]
```

I have tried to do like this,but it not come the exact result,

```
myClass myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myClass>(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to sanitise your JSON with some fancy regex madness (I'm no expert but this seems to work):

```
const str = '[\r\n  {\r\n    \"NewsDate\": \"2018-05-05T06:00:00\",\r\n    \"GeoDate\": \"2018-05-02T00:00:00\",\r\n  },{\r\n    \"NewsDate\": \"2018-06-05T06:00:00\",\r\n    \"GeoDate\": \"2018-06-02T00:00:00\",\r\n  }]';

const data = JSON.parse(str.replace(/\s\s+/g, '').replace(/\,(?!\s*?[\{\[\"\'\w])/g, ''));
```

You had some extra space in your output, but I think that's probably an artefact, you also had trailing commas which made `JSON.parse` burp a wee bit.

Then you need to extract the object keys and you probably want to check for objects with unique keys so set them to default when you define your columns:

```
const table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "columns": Object.keys(data.reduce((r, o) => Object.assign(r, o), {})).map(c => ({
    "title": c,
    "data": c,
    "default": ""
  })),
  "data": data
});
```

ES6 used, so you might want to check for polyfills if you need to target non-evergreen browsers. Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/jgbc1dwp/).